# htaccess rewrite query string

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following **.htaccess** file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^constant?([^/]+)=([^/]+) /index.php?url=constant&type=$1&task=$2 [L]
```

The last line isn't quite working or is being affected by the previous.

If `$_GET['url']` doens't exist in **DB** it fires **404**.

```
contan?x=y //gives 404
constant?x=y //works
```

That is how it shoud work.

**However,** when I use `var_dump($_GET);` *on line 1 of index* at `example.com/constant?x=y`

I only get `array(1) { ["url"]=> string(8) "constant" }`

Is the last line being affected by the previous, could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: TBH I'm lost as what are you trying to achieve. This rule `RewriteRule ^constant?([^/]+)=([^/]+)` does not make much sense for me -- it's wrong. Could you please tell how would you like to rewrite that URL (from URL => to URL) and I will do the rule for you. Also -- you are saying: `{ ["url"]=> string(8) "constant" }` -- that is correct. If not -- what do you expect there?

Comment: I was expecting : `{ ["url"]=> string(8) "constant", ["type"]=>..., ["task"]=>..., }`. You're right about the `RewriteRule` I was trying to make a very simple url so : `example.com/index.php?a=x&b=y&c=z` to `example.com/x?y=z`. Which is misusing `?` and `=`. The server see it as `$_GET['y'] == z`. Is something like this achievable? Or as simple? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these rules:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# specific rule
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=]+)=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^(constant)$ /index.php?url=$1&type=%1&task=%2 [L]

# general catch-all
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

You cannot match query string in rewrite rule: rewrite rule only matches path part of the URL while query string has to be matched via rewrite condition.

Obviously, this specific rule will not be triggered if you do not provide enough parameters, e.g. `/constant` or `/constant?say=`.

---

If you add `QSA` flag to that rule, then you will be able to pass other parameters as well (but it will pass whole query string over): e.g. `/constant?say=meow&loud=yes` will become `/index.php?url=constant&type=say&task=meow&say=meow&loud=yes` -- it can be useful depending on your URLs and tasks performed:

```
RewriteRule ^(constant)$ /index.php?url=$1&type=%1&task=%2 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the query string append flag, `QSA`, to ensure you pass the existing GET vars. Otherwise, they are overwritten by the `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteRule ^constant?([^/]+)=([^/]+) /index.php?url=constant&type=$1&task=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `L` flag in the first rewrite rule, and since that rule always matches, you will never trigger the last rule.

Try to put the last rule before the first rule (and add the `QSA` as Jason McCreary said).

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^constant?([^/]+)=([^/]+) index.php?url=constant&type=$1&task=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This would give me `array(1) { ["url"] string(9) "index.php"; }` (404) on everypage. Thanks though!

Comment: I think the slash before the `index.php` shouldn't be there. I removed it from my answer, please try it again.

Comment: Still has same effect as before.